# How to auto refresh view when scrolling to the top on Android like ipad does

Tags: android

In my app, i've already have an AllContentListScreen which extends Activity. It also has a customlistview and a custom adapter which retrieves data. 
What I am going to implement is when i scroll the screen to the very top of view, a spinning wheel will show and the data will be auto refreshed. 
This is definitely a UI issue. Any proper solution will be highly appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: There's a few libraries already done for that purpose, for example: https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh

Comment: To be honest, I'm fresh for android dev, so here I'm willing to know for the current time how to do it in the UI part, i.e. just to show the spinning progress bar on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`Pull to Refresh`](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) library by Chris Banes.

Comment: Thanks but it's a little bit complicated for my app, coz only I want to implement is when I scroll the content list up to the very top, below the header, the refresh progress spinning stuff will show up and keep refreshing until data is all downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [android-pulltorefresh](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh) to do this,

Comment: Actually it's a good stuff and I implemented on my own in the app. Thanks

Comment: I'm new here and it seems a bit harder to find where to mark answered

Comment: you marked Leandros answer as answered already. http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png